How do I find the MasterUserOptions for an existing OpenSearch domain?
Suppose I have an OpenSearch domain that was configured on deployment with a master user IAM role. I now want to programmatically find that role from the cluster. (Or find it in the AWS console.) I've tried doing:
aws opensearch describe-domain-config --domain-name mydomain

But there doesn't seem to be anything about the master user in the response JSON - the AdvancedSecuritySections part of the result just looks like this:
        "AdvancedSecurityOptions": {
            "Enabled": true,
            "InternalUserDatabaseEnabled": false,
            "AnonymousAuthEnabled": false
        },


Where do I find the role?

You wont see find it from the was CLI nor trough the console.
There is a way to find it out form the open search dashboard: Login into the dashboard goto: Security -> Roles and then click on Backend Roles in the table. There you will see it
Or click on all_access role and again in the backend roles you will see it
